# Unable to plot background & bar color for TradingView in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-editor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heKZD.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR3TI.png)

I am trying to build a BUY/SELL Indicator for TradingView by EMA.

Conditions for BUY Signal:
The 9 EMA LINE (Green) is above the 18 EMA LINE (Red)

Conditions for SELL Signal:
The 9 EMA LINE (Green) is below the 18 EMA LINE (Red)

When the above conditions are met it should give the respective BUY or SELL signal.

But, I am not being able to fill background & plotbarcolor for the correct BUY/SELL signal that meets all the conditions.

My codes:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='EMA', overlay=true)

s9ema = ta.ema(close, 9)
s18ema = ta.ema(close, 18)

longCond = ta.crossover(s9ema, s18ema)
shortCond = ta.crossunder(s9ema, s18ema)

plotshape(series=longCond, title='BUY', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='BUY', size=size.small)
plotshape(series=shortCond, title='SELL', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='SELL', size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use bgcolor to plot background color and barcolor to plot the color of bar. example below

```
    //@version=5 
indicator(title='EMA', overlay=true)

s9ema = ta.ema(close, 9) 
s18ema = ta.ema(close, 18)


plot(s9ema,color=color.green)
plot(s18ema,color=color.red)
longCond = ta.crossover(s9ema, s18ema) 
shortCond = ta.crossunder(s9ema, s18ema)

bgcolor(s9ema>s18ema?color.new(color.green,70):s9ema<s18ema?color.new(color.red,70):na)
barcolor(s9ema>s18ema?color.new(color.green,40):s9ema<s18ema?color.new(color.red,40):na)

plotshape(series=longCond, title='BUY', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='BUY', size=size.small) 
plotshape(series=shortCond, title='SELL', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text='SELL', size=size.small)
```

Comment: that i doesn't able to code.

Comment: what bg color do you want to show on condition

Comment: light red & light green - say 50%

Comment: i have edited my answer to plot bgcolor and barcolor both with different transparency. you can change them as per need

Comment: yes but it's not appying to whole chart. it's just showing for signal candle only. want for entire trend.

Comment: Edit my answer to show for whole trend

Comment: it's almost done. but when there is a uptrend some times candle body & hair shows red & in down trend some times candle body & hair shows green.

Comment: you will have to add screenshot marking the ssame

Comment: sometimes if the height of candle is very small and price scale is small then it can appear different color, try zooming price scale on right side and hair color cannot be changed in pinescript

Comment: screenshot attached

Comment: sometimes if the height of candle is very small and price scale is small then it can appear different color, try zooming price scale on right side and hair color cannot be changed in pinescript –

Comment: ok then can we do buy/sell trendline with cloud like screenshot ??

Comment: you can post a separate question for trendline with examples

Comment: sure posted as a  separate question.

Comment: want supertrend signal into background.

Comment: how i can connect you rohit for other works??

Comment: rohit i want to same things into supertrend . how can it apply ??

Comment: how i can connect you rohit for other works??